# Odd Python Syntax?

Tags: python, mbed

When on GitHub, I stumbled upon this page (https://github.com/mbedmicro/pyOCD) which is there to help with using mbed boards. However, when i looked at their Hello World Example (below), i was real baffled. It uses an extremly odd python syntax (which is not valid as the complier threw an error).

Here it is :

```
from pyOCD.board import MbedBoard

import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

board = MbedBoard.chooseBoard()

target = board.target
flash = board.flash
target.resume()
target.halt()

print "pc: 0x%X" % target.readCoreRegister("pc")
    pc: 0xA64

target.step()
print "pc: 0x%X" % target.readCoreRegister("pc")
    pc: 0xA30

target.step()
print "pc: 0x%X" % target.readCoreRegister("pc")
   pc: 0xA32

flash.flashBinary("binaries/l1_lpc1768.bin")
print "pc: 0x%X" % target.readCoreRegister("pc")
   pc: 0x10000000

target.reset()
target.halt()
print "pc: 0x%X" % target.readCoreRegister("pc")
   pc: 0xAAC

board.uninit()
```

My issue is the "`pc: 0xAAC`" lines which appear littered accross the code. Is this some special type of coding? It doesnt work, so would someone please point towards maybe what the author was trying to get at?

Thank you

Comment: They embedded the output into the file.

Comment: How annoying. Those "pc: 0xAAC" lines should've been written as comments so that the code was runnable.

Comment: the layout of that example is extremely unfortunate. I'd suggest you ask the author to fix it by [opening an issue](https://github.com/mbedmicro/pyOCD/issues) or submitting a pull request

Comment: Opened [pull request](https://github.com/mbedmicro/pyOCD/pull/273/files)

Comment: @JanJongboom Fantastic! It's gonna make it a whole lot easier for future noobs like me :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an example, and they included the *expected output* in the text.

So the line

```
print "pc: 0x%X" % target.readCoreRegister("pc")
```

is expected to print something like

```
pc: 0xA64
```

So no, that's not valid Python code, and if you wanted to run the code yourself you should omit those lines.

They *could* have made this clearer by making those lines comments, of course, easily making the example runnable again:

```
print "pc: 0x%X" % target.readCoreRegister("pc")
# pc: 0xA64
```

Comment: .. or could have used the common markup for saying which lines are code and which ones are output, e.g. `>>> print "..."`

Comment: I opened a PR against the docs to clarify this: https://github.com/mbedmicro/pyOCD/pull/273